WHfB deployment through Intune - NLA issues
I hope this is in the right place.
So I have just deployed an on-prem NDES/SCEP server using this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lAONPNk6fm4&t=7019s
I have entered my SCEP server details into an Intune policy and my device has succesfully enrolled and picked up a certificate.
When entering my pin I am presented with this error message:
"The remote computer that you are trying to connect to requires network level authentication (NLA), but your windows domain controller cannot be contacted to perform NLA. You can try connecting to the remote computer using your username and password instead."
Turning off NLA on all of the servers is not an option. Its a security requirement for us.
Is there a way to get around this either on the client side or through the policy in Intune for SCEP?
I cannot turn NLA off on the servers that I am trying to connect to as this is controlled by GPO which cannot be changed for security purposes.
I have tried connecting to the RDP session using the remote credential guard flag by making a registry change and also using mstsc.exe /remoteGuard.

I turned off NLA on my test server which allowed me to use a pin but now I have a different issue.
I've raised a new question about it WHfB - Deployed through Intune but RDS servers still ask for credentials
